# Off hand equipment has confusing stats?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm working my way through Act 4 Nightmare as a Demon Hunter and I came across a quiver that, when equipped, would increase my damage by about 160 damage per second. This would be fine and all but when I compare it to the shield that I'm carrying I see that none of the quiver's stats are better, at all.

Do demon hunters get bonuses of any kind from carrying a quiver, or are the character stat screens inaccurate/unreliable for determining whether a piece of equipment is better or worse?

[image: screenshot detailing question]

Comment: Attack speed.  It's all about the attack speed.

Comment: leave the shield to your templar. he'd be happy to have it. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in DPS in this instance is caused by the Increased Attack Speed statistic on your quiver. Really the only stats on the shield you're currently using that are even relevant to Demon Hunters is the Vitality (health points) and resistances (not really that important depending on build, as they're physical resistance).

Increased Attack Speed on the other hand, works in synergy with every other damage statistic you have, to provide an increase to overall attack speed, which of course scales with statistics like Dexterity, Critical Change, Critical Damage, etc - by allowing you to attack more times per second.

The Demon Hunter class does not gain specific bonuses for simply using certain items in certain slots - the exception to this of course is based on the type of bow you use when using the Archery passive ability - but for the instance of shield vs quiver, there are no bonuses.

Comment: While this is strictly true it should be noted that quivers get increased attack speed "for free" rather than at the expense of other stats, and a fairly large amount of it at that. Additionally, it can be equipped along with a 2H ranged weapon, which other offhand slot items cannot.  For Demon Hunters, a quiver is nearly always the appropriate offhand choice.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I certainly would use anything other than a quiver for an offhand of a demon hunter.

Comment: I dunno, with the latest updates, I've seen some DH run around with a 300 dex 100 vit shield with 10 % crit chance and a heck lot of block and res all.

Comment: While in general, I would say run a DH with a quiver, this quiver isn't particularly good, and I'd be afraid of the cost to effective hit points from trading out the shield.

Comment: In this particular instance with *those two items* I would probably keep the shield until I could get a decent quiver. The ~1k health and block/physical resistance makes up a decent chunk of effective health for sure.